# Как передать в функцию двумерный массив , если не знаешь формат?

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно сделать функцию для того что бы заменить элементы двумерного массива на парные числа или на некоторые символы , отсюда выплывает вопрос:

**Как передать в функцию двумерный массив формата string или int ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно через generic's как-то так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeMagic(new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } });
    Console.WriteLine("");
    SomeMagic(new string[2, 2] { { "1", "2" }, { "3", "4" } });
}

static void SomeMagic<T>(T[,] array)
{
    foreach (var el in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el);
    }
}
```

Если не нравится generic, то сделайте две реализации метода(int, string)